# can not create has_many through associations, how to populate the tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, activerecord

I am creating a web app using rails 5 where a user can create groups and upload files to the group. I have created a user model, groups models and member model.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
     devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable


    groupify :group_member
    groupify :named_group_member

    validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
    has_many :members
    has_many :groups, through: :member
end

class Group < ApplicationRecord
    groupify :group, members: [:users, :assignments], default_members: :users

    has_many :members
    has_many :groups, through: :member
end

class Member < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :group
    belongs_to :user
end
```

I can create users and groups but i cant understand how to fill the member table. It consist of 2 columns, user_id and group_id.

EDIT:
 These are my migration files

```
class CreateMembers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :members do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :group_id

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :members , [:user_id,:group_id]
  end
end
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name ,              null: false
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at
      t.datetime :remember_created_at
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip


      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
  end
end
```

I do not have group_id in my users table, it is only in groups and member table.

Answer (score 0):

There is two way.

1) Create Member

```
Member.create(user_id: user_id, group_id: group_id)
```

2) Add Group id at User.groups_ids

```
ids = user.groups_ids
ids.push(group_id)
user.groups_ids = ids
```

Comment: or just `user.groups_ids << group_id`, instead of those three lines. And this one will immediately save this to database, so you don't have to perform `user.save` or something.

Comment: and how can i extract the group_id of the group that i have selected to add members into? As there may be several groups per user.

Comment: i do not have group_id in my User table. Can i still use the above statement? And all this will be in the user_controller or group_controller?

Comment: If User access groups via members, User has groups_ids.

Answer (score 0):

The through should be plural

```
through: :members
```